# Translator-ish Library

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this library:

1. `text_data(val)` translates `val` to computer data types
2. `colorcode()` returns the selected color in hex

Can you please tell me how I can make it better?

```
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
def text_data(text):
    texti = []
    binary = []
    ordv = []
    hexadecimal = []
    octal = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        j = ord(text[i])
        k = bin(ord(text[i]))
        l = hex(ord(text[i]))
        m = oct(ord(text[i]))
        k = k[2:]
        l = l[2:]
        m = m[2:]
        print(text[i], " ", j, " ", k, "", l, "", m)
        binary.append(k)
        ordv.append(j)
        hexadecimal.append(l)
        texti.append(text[i])
        octal.append(m)
        i += 1
    print("\n")
    print(binary)
    print("\n")
    print(ordv)
    print("\n")
    print(hexadecimal)
    print("\n")
    print(octal) 
def colorcode():
    return askcolor()[1]
print(colorcode())
```

Comment: Is this finished, working code? What is the intended usage of `text_data()`, and could you provide an example?

Comment: Are you the same person as [Bloxy Craft](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/145301/bloxy-craft)? If so, would you like to have your accounts [merged](/help/merging-accounts)?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

> ```
> i = 0
> while i < len(text):
>     j = ord(text[i])
>     ...
>     ...
>     ...
>     i += 1
> ```

and using `text[i]` for accessing individual elements (which is NOT a Pythonic way).
Get rid of `i` and write simply

```
for c in text:
    j = ord(c)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

---

> ```
>     j = ord(text[i])
>     k = bin(ord(text[i]))
>     l = hex(ord(text[i]))
>     m = oct(ord(text[i]))
> ```

After performing the first of those commands is `ord(text[i])` already in the variable `j`, isn't it? So why not reuse it in the rest of them:

```
for c in text:
    j = ord(c)
    k = bin(j)
    l = hex(j)
    m = oct(j)
```

---

Instead of

> ```
> print(text[i], " ", j, " ", k, "", l, "", m)
> ```

use the `format()` method and replacement fields `{}`:

```
print("{}   {}   {}  {}  {}".format(text[i], j, k, l, m))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about following the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)?
This style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important.

Your code will become

```
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor


def text_data(text):
    texti = []
    binary = []
    ordv = []
    hexadecimal = []
    octal = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(text):
        j = ord(text[i])
        k = bin(ord(text[i]))
        l = hex(ord(text[i]))
        m = oct(ord(text[i]))
        k = k[2:]
        l = l[2:]
        m = m[2:]
        print(text[i], " ", j, " ", k, "", l, "", m)
        binary.append(k)
        ordv.append(j)
        hexadecimal.append(l)
        texti.append(text[i])
        octal.append(m)
        i += 1
    print("\n")
    print(binary)
    print("\n")
    print(ordv)
    print("\n")
    print(hexadecimal)
    print("\n")
    print(octal)


def colorcode():
    return askcolor()[1]


print(colorcode())
```

Note particularly surrounding your function definitions with 2 blank lines.

(You may check it online: [PEP8 online](http://pep8online.com/) - as your original code, as this one.)